# What legal means does a USA President have to overturn a Supreme Court ruling?

Tags: united-states, president, supreme-court

It has been talked about much lately that the likely President elect of the United States (at the time of this writing) has expressed the desire to overturn certain Supreme Court of the United States (SCOTUS) rulings.

What legal means does the President of the United States (POTUS) actually have available, if any, to overturn SCOTUS rulings? And what are the checks and balances, if any, against those actions?

Comment: Worth noting that originally the Suprene Court couldn't do judicial review, so they didn't have the ability to make rulings as we know them today. Thus the checks and balances for the judicial branch are not as firmly described in the Constitution as those for the other branches.

Comment: This is going to take me more than a day to answer.  It would be better if you could narrow in on a specific case. Is there a ruling you have in mind.?

Comment: @KDog IIRC, few SCOTUS rulings have ever been overturned, so I'm not sure how to go about framing it more specifically.

Comment: Are you looking for something really detailed?  Cause this is a really serious question that would involve a great deal of investment of research and time.   If it's cursory interest, the below answer suffices ok, more or less.  As is, this question is really hypothetical and I am inclined to spike it.

Comment: @KDog I don't see how it's hypothetical. I'm asking about what powers a certain office has in relation to another branch of the government. As Thunderforge mentioned, the US Constitution isn't necessarily clear on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways.

1)  Get Congress to change the law.

2)  Convince the public that the issue is not a federal issue, but rather something that people should deal with personally or locally.

3)  Re-litigate the issues, especially after appointing new Justice(s).  As of 2016, there is a vacant seat on the U.S. Supreme Court.

4)  Re-litigate the issues, after getting Congress to restrict the Supreme Court's jurisdiction.

5)  Follow the procedures to amend the Constitution.

6)  Emulate Andrew Jackson's actions leading to the Trail of Tears.  ["Justice Marshall has made his decision:  Now let him enforce it."](http://quotationsbook.com/quote/45577/)

Options 1-5 are intentional parts of the system of "checks and balances".  Option 6 risks defunding (by Congress), nullification (by states), impeachment, losing elections, assassination, and/or civil war.

Comment: What can POTUS do to initiate re-litigation?

Comment: Regarding number 6, none of them came to pass for Andrew Jackson.  What were the actual implications for a committed President standing up to the Judiciary.

Comment: @CreationEdge - The President can initiate re-litigation by either committing an action that he knows will cause someone to sue, or by having the Justice Department sue someone.

Comment: Okay, so one of POTUS's explicit powers is to order the Justice Department to instigate a suit regarding a relevant SCOTUS decision?

Comment: @KDog - Andrew Jackson was stronger than these checks and balances.  He had already:  Forced 90-day-service state militia to fight for the duration of a war.  Won a major battle after a peace treaty was signed.  Convincingly won the 1828 election after the fiasco of the 1824 election.  Survived an assassination attempt.  Destroyed a National Bank  (similar to the Federal Reserve, but even more corrupt).  Stared down South Carolina's attempt at nullifying tariff laws.  Averted a civil war.

Comment: @CreationEdge  It would be more accurate to say that one of the president's powers is to order the Justice Department to sue someone (or charge someone with a crime).  Raising the relevant legal point would have to happen naturally in the suit.  This is more of an effective or implicit power.

Comment: It's probably noteworthy that there is currently a vacant seat.

Comment: The President can also wait for a Supreme Court justice to die/retire, then nominate another justice. Additionally he can ask Congress to increase the number of justices so he can nominate justices to comprise the majority. These political maneuvers are otherwise known as "stacking the court".

Comment: @Jasper: I think it was intended that if the Supreme Court issued rulings that were totally out of line, the other branches of government might ignore it, but that a President who wantonly ignored Supreme Court rulings that were widely regarded as legitimate would face impeachment.  IMHO, Marbury v. Madison has been misinterpreted giving the Court excessively god-like status.  When MvM said the Court's job is to say what the law is, that meant that if Court is doing its job, what it says and what the law is will be one and the same.  That doesn't imply the court might not fail to do its job.